# Swift TapGestureRecognizer and UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift so i'm sorry for any type of mistakes.
In my View Controller i have a view, CanvasView, and i want the user clicks on a button and add a shape where taps. I create a uiview named ShapeSquare and I have three buttons with three different shapes. Unfortunately i don't understand where i'm wrong. This is only a part of the code.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

```
@IBOutlet weak var CanvasView: CanvasView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("didTap")))
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    CanvasView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    CanvasView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)

}
func didTap(tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint = tapGR.location(in: CanvasView)
    let shapeView = ShapeSquare(origin: tapPoint)
    CanvasView.addSubview(shapeView)

}


@IBAction func SquareShape(_ sender: UIButton) {
    CanvasView.setNeedsDisplay()       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1-

```
let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
```

2-

```
@objc func didTap(_ tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
```